# Intercepting error handling with loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there somewhere complete, consistent and well documented source of information on error handling in loopback?

Things like error codes and their meaning, relation with http statuses. I've already read their docs and have not found anything like this.

I would like to translate all the messages to add multi language support to my app. I would also like to add my custom messages, with their code and to use it consistently with other loopback errors.

In order to achieve this, I need to **intercept all the errors** (I've done this already) and to know all the possible different codes, so I can translate them.

For example, if there is an error with code 555, I have to know what it means and treat it accordingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show an actual example ?

Comment: I've just edited my question and clarify my real focus (error messages/codes customization)

Comment: I think I have an idea of what is going on. Can you also show the contents of `server/model-config.json` to confirm ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? My model-config.json is quite standard, generated by loopback. I need to customize the error handling...

Comment: The entire file. I suspect you are missing some models, such as the access token model, which is why loopback is throwing 500 all over the place

Comment: This is possible to happen if you used a blank template for scaffolding the app

Comment: This single example does not matter at all, I'm not trying to solve that one, but overall error handling. I want to now all the possible error codes and how can I translate them as well as consistently add new ones, following the same logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need to "catch" all the messages and translate them

This is the beginning of an answer. You can write an error-handling middleware that will intercept any error returned by the server. You will need in turn to implement the logic for making the translation.

```
module.exports = function() { 
   return function logError(err, req, res, next) { 
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERR', req.url, err);
      }
      next();
   };
};
```

This middleware must be configured to be called in the `final` phase. Save the code above in log-error.js for instance, then modify `server/middleware.json`

```
{ "final": { "./middleware/log-error": {} } }
```

> I need a full list of loopback codes/messages

I'm pretty sure there is no such thing. Errors are build and returned all over the place in the code, not centralized anywhere.

Comment: This is not solving anything, I know these pages. Please read carefully again my question. I need to know ALL THE POSSIBLE error codes, in order to translate them and have full control over them. I can always create a custom error with no problem, but what should I do with all kinds of built-in errors that I do not know?

Comment: You do realize I'm the only person trying to solve your problem here ?

Comment: Especially since clearly you haven't clicked the first link. Error code 555 does not exist, it is not a valid HTTP status code. All error codes loopback will return are HTTP status codes.

Comment: Now, if your question is to translate all errors MESSAGES possibly thrown by loopback, then you might be interested in [`strong-globalize`](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-globalize).

Comment: sorry for the tone. I'm not searching the cause of that particular error message, but to understand the general err handling  mechanism. I need to "catch" all the messages and translate them. I need a full list of loopback codes/messages, so I can do it... Without using external tools.

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer, I have an idea that might get you started.

Comment: I know about the error handling middleware, no prob with this. And I am now almost convinced that your last sentence is correct - no centralized err handling in loopback, meaning - must be built from the ground up if one needs to do sth with it (translate for example).
Thank you very much, I'll accept your answer in a couple of days if nobody shows some other reasonable option.

Comment: Sure no problem. But really explore strong-globalize, I am not entirely sure it's what you need, but it's required in pretty much any loopback module I have seen, so it's not really an external tool. Good luck on your problem