# How to make a simple API for post method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code in Ionic app but I don't know how to make an API with Node.js to send this values to sever only by using Node.js.

```
submitForm() {
    let headers = new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = JSON.stringify({
      Value1: this.form.value1,
      Value2: this.form.value2,
      Value3: this.form.value3
    });   
    console.log(data);

    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/calculate';
console.log(url);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(url, data, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('API Response : ', response.status);
          resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('API Error : ', error.status);
          console.error('API Error : ', JSON.stringify(error));
          reject(error.json());
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to send 'data's to 'http://localhost:3000/calculate' using POST? Are you using jQuery? If so, I could show you the AJAX method.

Comment: Dear @bobwirka Im using ionic framework and localhost will be change to server address. Localhost is for testing in production environment.I had to make a simple API that Ionic App by using post method sends values to server and in serve we can send it to console or do mathematical operations over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example Node.js project that illustrates client/server request/response using AJAX and JSON. It "requires" only 'http', 'path', and 'fs'.

It implements a 'calculate' function server-side, and has a web page that presents 3 input boxes and a 'Calculate' button.

It's on Github: "https://github.com/bobwirka/NodeClientServer.git"

Hope this will be of help.

Comment: Just committed a few changes. Have to admit I haven't cloned the repo and tried to run it...just committed it. Will clone and try it.

Comment: Just cloned the repository and ran it using 'npm start'; it's ok.

Comment: I should add, however, that it probably won't work in Windows. The whole thing was done in Linux, and there are symlinks in the project. Not a very good chance they'd work in Windows.

Comment: If you're going to use this in Windows, you'd have to replace the symlinks in the /client folder with the actual files from node_modules.

Comment: Sorry to keep changing things, but I've replaced the symlinks with files, so a fresh checkout or pull should fix any symlink issues.

Comment: Would you share your changes? Thanks.

Comment: I add these lines to right after `http.createServer` funcution `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`
`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');`
`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');`
`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);`

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use `ExpressJS`. Following example may help you

Create a directory lets called `api` with following 2 files

create `app.js` in api directory

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.post('/calculate', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    console.log('Here are your data: ', data);
    res.json({message: 'you posted successfully'});
});


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', function(){
  console.error('Error')
});
server.on('listening', function(){
  console.log('server started on port ' + port)
});
```

create `package.json` file in api directory

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "express": "~4.15.2"
  }
}
```

now open command line/terminal and install dependencies by running following command(you must go to inside `api` directory)

```
npm install
```

now you can run by just running either `npm start` or `node app.js`

You should google for learning and studying and post questions for bug/issue

**Update: without any dependencies or library but not recommended**

It will be better to use http framework like express, sailsjs, etc. but if you like to play with nodejs then following example may help you

```
var http = require('http');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var contentType = req.headers['content-type'];
  var rawData = '';
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    rawData += chunk;
  });
  req.on('end', function () {
    if(req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/calculate' && contentType.indexOf('application/json')>-1){
      try {
        const data = JSON.parse(rawData);
        console.log('Your data is here: ', data);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        var result = {message: 'you have posted successfully'}
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        res.writeHead(400, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        var result = {message: e.message}
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    } else {
      res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      var result = {message: 'Url not found'}
      res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
  });
});
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', function(){
  console.error('Error')
});
server.on('listening', function(){
  console.log('server started on port ' + port)
});
```

Comment: Dear @arif-khan, thanks for your sharing this code. the main problem is that i had to make it only work with Nodjs not additional packages  like expressjs.

Comment: @RSA I have added `node.js` only code. You may like to add more thing as you needed like routing, etc.